# Need to Change the timer

Tags: magento-1.9, time

I need to know from where i can make changes in the time

[image]

In the picture shown above , you can see a  "clock" and "end in"

Need to know from where i can access the area in the backend

please help

Comment: it completely depends on your theme/extension layout

Answer (score 1):

Check by enabling Template path hint in Magento, you will get from which file that clock and text is coming. 
If then also you are unable to find then check in which cms page it's coming as there can be any template file of static block called.

Comment: I have found the template path and the code i have got is                                      `<div class="count-down-time">
      <span class="fa fa-clock-o"  style = "color: #009688 !important;font-size:15px"></span>
   <span >end in </span>         
     <div id="countbox_<?php echo $this->getIdentifier(); ?>" class="timer-view"></div>
  </div>  `    but from here i cannot set anything instead only see it in the view page , will there be any place from where i can set the time ??

Comment: id="countbox_<?php echo $this->getIdentifier(); ?>"  This thing is setting the end time maybe by some js is done there.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?